# Models Twitching Randomly (Render Only)

Tags: rendering, modifiers, armature, motion-blur

SOLUTION:
w/ thanks to Rich Sedman:

The use of the array modifier was the cause. Since it used very large values to cover a large area, it essentially created huge meshes, which are difficult for Blender to accurately find the location of; causing them to jitter in camera space, causing the blurring.

The answer was to remove the largest of the arrays and just use duplicates; keeping the array only for small scales.

---

When rendering out this scene, the characters I have walking around appear to vibrate rapidly so that they appear blured and partially transparent. This is linked to the motion blur, since it doesn't do this if motion blur is disabled.

https://youtu.be/tYqIh_BxnHQ  Issues start ~4 seconds in.

This is the animation recorded from Blender (no motion blur, no rendering, just recording the viewport). https://youtu.be/Z4R7saAo6nw. As you see, no glitching jitters appear.

There is nothing I can see that would cause this animation. The only animations one each of these are 1 animation for 'walking' and a second animation track in the NLA for the 'motion' of walking (linear transformation).

However, these characters are all in an array. I have the base model; a first array of 1 instance for a characters stood close by; a second array of 6 instances for people walking behind; and a third array of 1 instance for the characters on the other side of the road.

This could be the source I suppose? But that doesn't change that there's nothing I can find that would create this twitching effect (in terms of an animation).

Here you can see the Arrays I mentioned. This is just 1 model of a character; the rest is instanced by the three Arrays.
[image]

Here's the NLA tracks in use. They don't contain anything to cause this juttering, and as you see there's no other keyframes on the timeline.
[image]

I'm at a loss on this whole thing. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Just a thought, but could this be related to floating point innaccuracies with a very large scene scale? How big is your scene? What camera clipping limits do you have set? If those are very large, try reducing to see if it resolves the problem. ie, it could be that large scales are resulting in floating point innaccuraries that are meaning that the location of the objects are seemingly jittering in camera space. This could affect the motion blur since it would appear that the objects are moving within the frame.

Comment: Well this seems to have worked. The camera clipping wasn't an issue but having an array of objects so far appart apparently did? I think the interesting thing you brought up about the screen space floating point thing is the cause. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to be able to help. That makes sense that it was the array modifier with large values as it would have effectively created huge meshes. Please consider adding an answer to your own question to explain the solution for other people with the same issue.